# How to disable screen timeout on NativeActivity

Tags: android

I am developing app on NativeActivity(only C/C++).
I want to disable screen timeout.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 8):

In case the OP is still looking for an answer or for anyone like me who finds topic this while searching, here's how you do it:

```
#include <android/window.h>

[...]

// place this in your init function once you have a valid window
ANativeActivity_setWindowFlags(pYourAppStruct->activity, AWINDOW_FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, 0);
```